# open new window and pass collection to viewmodel using mvvm

Tags: asp.net, wpf, silverlight, mvvm

I have a view which consists of a button when i click i want to open window in which i want to pass observable collection to viewmodel of the new window open.I am using below code it is working but i am not sure it is mvvm pattern or not.

**ViewCode:**

```
NewWindow newWindowDialog;
newWindowDialog = new NewWindow()
{
    newWindowDialogCollection = suppliersList,
    Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow
};
newWindowDialog.ShowDialog();
```

**NewWindow Dialog Code:**

```
public partial class NewWindow : Window
{
    public NewWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        newWindowDialogCollection = new ObservableCollection<SModel>();
        DataContext = this;
    }
    public ObservableCollection<ISupplierModel> newWindowDialogCollection { get; set; }
}
```

In xaml "**newWindowDialogCollection**" act as my data source for binding

But i am not sure above way is right way to impliment to open new window and pass collection. and i want to do it by pure mvvm & viewmodel.
    Please let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new window in a viewmodel couples the View and the ViewModel layers tightly, which defeats the purpose of MVVM.

Also, you shouldn't have business data in the View, but in a ViewModel instead, even with dialogs.

What you'll see some MVVM frameworks do is implementing service classes for everything that is not (easily) manageable by either the Model, the View or the ViewModel. Displaying dialogs is one of those things.

I'll use the example of Catel to demonstrate.
Catel offers a [IUIVisualizerService](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/UIVisualizerService) interface, that you can inject in the constructor of your viewmodel:

```
public MyViewModel(IUIVisualizerService visualizerService)
{
     this._visualizerService = visualizerService;
}
```

And to open a new dialog, since Catel internally matches views and viewmodels, you simple create the dialog's viewmodel and resolve the appropriate view. This way, you can pass you data to the viewmodel's constructor as you please:

```
var viewModel = new MyViewModel(suppliersList);
_visualizerService.Show(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a window service that is responsible for open the window and then inject your view model with such a service. You then call the service's ShowWindow method to open the window from your view model, e.g.:

**Service:**

```
public interface IWindowService
{
    void ShowWindow(ObservableCollection<string> collection);
}

public class WindowService : IWindowService
{
    public void ShowWindow(ObservableCollection<string> collection);
    {
        NewWindow newWindowDialog = new NewWindow()
        {
            newWindowDialogCollection = collection,
            Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow
        };
        newWindowDialog.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**View Model:**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly IWindowService _service;
    public ViewModel(IWindowService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    //...
    public void OpenCommandExecuted()
    {
        _service.ShowWindow(_theCollectionToPass);
    }
}
```

Using this approach the view model only knows about an interface that you can easily unit test, without actually opening up a window, by providing a mock implementation of the interface.

Comment: what about this line  newWindowDialogCollection = collection, i need to take " newWindowDialogCollection " in window code behind beacuse main purpose comes now how collection goes to new window..

Comment: Pass a reference to the collection to the ShowWindow method and set a property of NewWindow or its view model to this collection in the WindowService class.